# Why does Selenium WebDriver doesn't work on redirect url from server?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I have been using Selenium WebDriver to automate the test on web application. 
I have a situation lets say I am performing automation on www.abc.com, after submitting one of the pages i am redirected to paypal.com where i enter all the payment details and submit taking me back to www.abc.com with error as "error processing request" but it works good when I try it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: what did u try? what is the html? what is the error?

Comment: hey it takes me back to the original domain with error as "Error processing the request" Do u think it could be an "same origin policy" issue since payment gateway has different domain than the one we start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my browser version to the latest one from 21.0 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: May I know which browser did you use? I am having the same issue two years later.

Comment: I was using firefox browser.